# un-escaped _server variable in settings.php - bad idea right?

Tags: security, configuration

I recently started working for a new company hosting drupal sites that is using a switch statement within the settings.php for multiple environments. I am accustomed to using multi-site and am exploring the feasibility of having configurations like this.

What concerns me is the lack of any sanitation or escaping of the variable and using it in its raw form. Is this a terrible idea or is it fine if we start sanitizing the 'http_host' variable?

Code:

```
    switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {

    //Live Settings
    case (preg_match('/^www\.domain\.com$/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : !$_SERVER ['HTTP_HOST']) :
    case (preg_match('/^web001\.domain\.domroot\.com$/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : !$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) :
    case (preg_match('/^web002\.domain\.domroot\.com$/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : !$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) :
    //Include file that contains sensitive db string
    include_once 'sites/default/settings.live.php';
    break;

    ...

     }
```

Comment: After 13(?) years of doing PHP, I had no idea that you didn't have to use a literal in a case test :/

Comment: Is there anyone out there that has an argument in favor of using switch in this manner?

Comment: The switch statement above can be simplified to `switch (TRUE) {`, followed by each 'case' statement with the trinary operator (?:) removed.  Once you do this, it should be clear that this structure is equivalent to the canonical form, which would be a sequence of if / elseif statements.

Comment: Forgive me I should be more clear. I meant is there any benefit from using the case statements in a settings.php in Drupal 7 over using the multi site configuration?

Answer (score 4):

- D7 ? No need to do this!

First, talking about what you are doing, if it's for a Drupal 7 site, you do not need to do this in the first place. 
Read the `sites/example.sites.php` for multisite settings.

- `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is [almost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6474936/784877) safe.

See this great answer about how much secure `$_SERVER` variables are.

- There is no point of sanitizing *it* either.

From Drupal.org post [Writing Secure code](https://drupal.org/writing-secure-code),

> Whether you are writing a PHP snippet or an entire module, it is
>   important to keep your code secure. Use check functions on output to
>   prevent cross site scripting attacks
>
> No piece of user-submitted content should ever be placed as-is into
>   HTML.

But you are not outputting anything or populating any variable so you do not need to sanitize any **output** here.

[image: Output ?]

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a standard case for the use of Drupal's [sites.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites!example.sites.php/7) file

Comment: Yes Ayesh, Yes this is D7. And thank you for the reply.